# Can not get new access token microsoft api with app id via postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman, access-token, microsoft-graph-api

I created my app in https:// apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList by hotmail account

then I tried to get access token for PUT text file to onedrive or sharedrive.

I copied app id and secret code to postman in Authorization tab and chose OAuth 2.0

Then I filled

.
.

Auth url: https:// login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Access token url: https:// login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

Client id: 'my app id'

Client secret: 'my app secret password'

scope: user.read

Grant type: Authorization Code

.
.

then pressed request token

After that new window started and let me sign in microsoft account, and I used this account  => xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com

after sign in it showed this message

We're unable to complete your request
Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.

How can I fix it.

I have to use  upload text file to one drive in background in react native app.

I tried this is my react native app and it showed the same message.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please using fiddle or other browser's developer tool to check the authentication request and confirm what is the detail error message which block the sign-in process .

I guess you don't correctly set the callback URL in your Azure AD APP . Then after entering the username , it will show above error . If using fiddler to track the request , you should get error like :
[image]

The solution is adding the postman's callback URL to your app setting :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **Microsoft Personal Account** just follow the steps that I shared in [Tenant does not have a SPO license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802055/tenant-does-not-have-a-spo-license/66733599#66733599).