# upload file to onedrive using REST API

Tags: azure, rest, onedrive

I trying to upload a simpale text as file to oneDrive using REST API.

I Create App inportal.azure.com
And i add the follow API permissions
[image]

I create a token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/< My tenantName>/oauth2/v2.0/token
Send the follow pramters:

- grant_type client_credentials
- client_id My client id
- client_secret My client secret
- scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Keep-Alive true

I send it as a post and get a JSON with the token.

Then I try to upload the text as file.

using the follow URL
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root://test.txt:/content

- authorization Bearer {my token String}
- Content-Type text/plain
- Body "The string that needs to upload"

  {
  "error":
  {
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Unable to retrieve tenant service info.",
  "innerError": {
  "request-id": "098f37d5-96fd-44d0-905b-c147eac223f5",
  "date": "2020-05-19T11:43:03"
  }
  }
  }

[image]

What I do Wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Microsoft Graph to upload file to onedrive, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
PUT /drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
PUT /users/{user-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

For example, upload file to one user's onedrive in your tenant

1. Create Azure AD application
2. [Configure Permissions for the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#2-configure-permissions-for-microsoft-graph). (Microsoft graph -> Application Permissions -> **Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All**)
3. Get access token

```
Post  https://login.microsoftonline.com/< My tenantName>/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded 

grant_type= client_credentials
&client_id= My client id
&client_secret= My client secret
&scope =https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

4 upload file to one user's onedrive

```
Put https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user object id or upn>/drive/items/root:/test.txt:/content
Authorization : Bearer <Access token>

Content-Type: text/plain


<file content>
```

[image]

Besides, please note that when we use API to upload file, the size of file cannot be larger than 4MB. If you want to upload large file, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0) and  the [document](https://dev.to/cesarcodes/uploading-large-files-to-onedrive-with-microsoft-graph-api-4lo7)

Comment: Thanks for explaination. I try the same way as you suggest But still i'm getting same error as shown in question. **Unable to retrieve tenant service info.**  I try to call this API **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root**

Comment: @khushi Could you please provide the detailed error message?

Comment: Here is detailed error message
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unable to retrieve tenant service info.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-24T09:12:22",
      "request-id": "7f7685c2-c561-4a79-9fb3-50674d5b4055"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has a similar issue, a few days ago, I had the same problem, and I partially solve it by creating a tenant in Azure Active Directory(ADD) and switching to this new one. But with this new tenant for personal Microsoft accounts, I had the `"Tenant does not have a SPO license."` error. This happened because ADD app type was wrong, as well as my endpoints, to use with a personal Microsft account.

If you have a business account, you should use the account with office 365 business subscription and configure your tenant to use it. Like this will work as you configured.

If you have a personal Microsoft account, I shared a step-by-step how to solve this problem and the limitations for our account type [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802055/tenant-does-not-have-a-spo-license/66733599#66733599).

Answer (score 0):

To upload file (<4MB in size) to your OneDrive in the tenant.

This command will do the job

```
foo@bar:~$ ACCESS_TOKEN=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IlZ0MVBN...
foo@bar:~$ curl -X PUT 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/myNewFolder/file.tgz:/content' -H 'Authorization: Bearer '"${ACCESS_TOKEN}"'' -T test.tgz
```