# Upload file to OneDrive using ASP.Net Core Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to upload file to OneDrive using Code below. For this I first created the Azure AD application and then created the ASP.Net Core Console Application to upload file to OneDrive using ([this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-access-file-data/5-exercise-upload-files-onedrive))
When I run the application, it asks for username and password in the console so I gave my Azure username and passwork but then it displays error "MsalServiceException: Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (NotAcceptable)" as shown in image. I have also given Application ID and Tenant ID in appsettings.json file.
Do you have any idea why this error occurs and how to resolve this error?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRJEq.png)
[Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8COCS.png)

Program.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Helpers;
using System;

namespace OneDriveConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var config = LoadAppSettings();
            if (config == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid appsettings.json file.");
                return;
            }

            var userName = ReadUsername();
            var userPassword = ReadPassword();

            var client = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(config, userName, userPassword);

            // request 1 - upload small file to user's onedrive
            var fileName = "smallfile.txt";
            var filePath = Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), fileName);
            Console.WriteLine("Uploading file: " + fileName);

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            var uploadedFile = client.Me.Drive.Root
                                          .ItemWithPath("smallfile.txt")
                                          .Content
                                          .Request()
                                          .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream)
                                          .Result;
            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded to: " + uploadedFile.WebUrl);
        }

        private static IConfigurationRoot LoadAppSettings()
        {
            try
            {
                var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                  .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                                  .Build();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["applicationId"]) ||
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["tenantId"]))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return config;
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static IAuthenticationProvider CreateAuthorizationProvider(IConfigurationRoot config, string userName, SecureString userPassword)
        {
            var clientId = config["applicationId"];
            var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{config["tenantId"]}/v2.0";

            List<string> scopes = new List<string>();
            scopes.Add("User.Read");
            scopes.Add("Files.Read");
            scopes.Add("Files.ReadWrite");
            var cca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                                                    .WithAuthority(authority)
                                                    .Build();
            return MsalAuthenticationProvider.GetInstance(cca, scopes.ToArray(), userName, userPassword);
        }

        private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(IConfigurationRoot config, string userName, SecureString userPassword)
        {
            var authenticationProvider = CreateAuthorizationProvider(config, userName, userPassword);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
            return graphClient;
        }

        private static SecureString ReadPassword()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your password");
            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo c = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (c.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    break;
                }
                password.AppendChar(c.KeyChar);
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            return password;
        }

        private static string ReadUsername()
        {
            string username;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your username");
            username = Console.ReadLine();
            return username;
        }
    }
}
```

MsalAuthenticationProvider.cs

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace Helpers
{
    public class MsalAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private static MsalAuthenticationProvider _singleton;
        private IPublicClientApplication _clientApplication;
        private string[] _scopes;
        private string _username;
        private SecureString _password;
        private string _userId;

        private MsalAuthenticationProvider(IPublicClientApplication clientApplication, string[] scopes, string username, SecureString password)
        {
            _clientApplication = clientApplication;
            _scopes = scopes;
            _username = username;
            _password = password;
            _userId = null;
        }

        public static MsalAuthenticationProvider GetInstance(IPublicClientApplication clientApplication, string[] scopes, string username, SecureString password)
        {
            if (_singleton == null)
            {
                _singleton = new MsalAuthenticationProvider(clientApplication, scopes, username, password);
            }

            return _singleton;
        }

        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var accessToken = await GetTokenAsync();

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
        }

        public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_userId))
            {
                try
                {
                    var account = await _clientApplication.GetAccountAsync(_userId);

                    if (account != null)
                    {
                        var silentResult = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
                        return silentResult.AccessToken;
                    }
                }
                catch (MsalUiRequiredException) { }
            }

            var result = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(_scopes, _username, _password).ExecuteAsync();
            _userId = result.Account.HomeAccountId.Identifier;
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Username/Password (ROPC) is not supported for personal accounts. See the **Important** [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

You need to login with **Work or School Account**(looks like `xxxxxxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com`) instead of gmail or other third-party mailboxes. You could add the user(Navigate to Azure Active Directory -> User -> New User -> Create User), and then login in with this.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: After login with School Account. I added a new user. Now when I give username and password in my console App, it shows "Tenant does not have a SPO license" . Do you have any idea why this error occurs?

Comment: @AliHaider This issue will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46869065/13308381