# I have an error when i tried to upload a file from my system to ONE Drive using PHP

Tags: php, azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, licensing

I'm trying to upload a file to My One Drive Account using PHP.

But i got this error `"Tenant does not have a SPO license."`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/6290b46e-d76b-444d-9964-23d66beed506/drive/root/children/file.txt/content` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Tenant does not have a SPO license.","innerError"
```

My Current code is

```
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\GraphServiceClient;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model\EmailAddress;
use \GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri;

$client = new Client();

$tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token";
$response = $client->post($tokenEndpoint, [
'form_params' => [
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
],
]);

$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

$accessToken = $data['access_token'];
//var_dump($accessToken);

$uploadEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$userId/drive/root/children/file.txt/content";

//$uploadEndpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children/file.txt/content';
$filePath = '/var/www/html/folder/info.txt';

$response = $client->put($uploadEndpoint, [
'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    'Content-Type' => 'text/plain', // Change the content type as needed
],
'body' => fopen($filePath, 'r'), // Read the file contents
]);

// Check the response
if ($response->getStatusCode() == 201) {
echo 'File uploaded successfully!';
} else {
echo 'File upload failed. Status Code: ' . $response->getStatusCode();
echo 'Response: ' . $response->getBody();
}
```

Can anyone Provide me the solution for that how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does the tenant have office 365 license?

Comment: No I didn't have office 365 license is it required or any other way to do that without taking license

Comment: It is required to have office 365 license to perform the action.

Answer (score 0):

The error ***"Tenant does not have a SPO license"*** usually occurs if the tenant does not have the required licenses to perform the action.

To resolve the error, make sure to add **Office 365** license to your tenant.

[image]

I generated **access token** by using below parameters via postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

For **sample**, using the above access token I am able to upload the file to OneDrive successfully:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxx@onmicrosoft.com/drive/root:/test.txt:/content
Content-Type: text/plain 

The contents of the file
```

[image]

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, check this [**Microsoft QnA**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1075881/error-tenant-does-not-have-a-spo-license-for-perso) by CarlZhao-MSFT.

**Reference:**

[microsoft graph api - Tenant does not have a SPO license - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802055/tenant-does-not-have-a-spo-license) by Dan Kershaw - MSFT

Comment: Thanks Rukmini for your answer i still didn't have that license when i have it i will try it and if i face any issue will paste it here.